# Report portal API rate limit

Tags: api, limit, reportportal

Does anyone know API rate limit for Report portal API, I can't seem to find any on it's official documentation or on git repo (https://github.com/reportportal/service-api)

Answer (score 0):

There is no rate limiter in `service-api` or anywhere else in Report Portal. It consumes as many requests as you send, depending on your hardware.